# TinyTds::Error: Procedure expects parameter

Tags: ruby, sql-server, activerecord, tiny-tds

Given the following ruby:

```
    sql2 = 'SELECT (CASE WHEN freq = 0 THEN \'pass\' ELSE \'fail\' END) FROM ( 
SELECT COUNT(*) freq FROM Grant_Award WHERE Grant_Award.org_ticker IS NULL )x;'
    pp ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql2)

    sql1 = "SELECT (CASE WHEN freq = 0 THEN 'pass' ELSE 'fail' END) FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) freq FROM Grant_Award WHERE Grant_Award.org_ticker IS NULL )x;"
    pp ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql1)

    sql0 = File.readlines(File.join(BASE,'db','scripts','test','pass_or_fail.sql'))
    sql = (sql0.map {|l| l.strip}).join(' ')
    pp sql
    pp ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql)
```

The above produces the following results:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Result:0x38b0ce0
 @column_types={},
 @columns=[""],
 @hash_rows=nil,
 @rows=[["pass"]]>

#<ActiveRecord::Result:0x38b5ae0
 @column_types={},
 @columns=[""],
 @hash_rows=nil,
 @rows=[["pass"]]>

"SELECT (CASE WHEN freq = 0 THEN 'pass' ELSE 'fail' END) FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) freq FROM Grant_Award WHERE Grant_Award.org_ticker IS NULL )x;"

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver/database_statements.rb:336:in `each': TinyTds::Error: Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.: EXEC sp_executesql 'SELECT (CASE WHEN freq = 0 THEN ''pass'' ELSE ''fail'' END) FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) freq FROM Grant_Award WHERE Grant_Award.org_ticker IS NULL )x;' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

The first two attempts at executing the sql return just fine.  The third one, which is read from a file into an array and then joined, bombs.  I know this must have something to do with the treatment of strings.  But I cannot figure this out.

What am I doing wrong?  Why does it (tinytds or activerecord?) think this is a stored procedure?

What I want to do is have a whole bunch of sql scripts in a folder and then execute them one by one.

Details: ruby 1.9.3, activerecord (4.2.0), and tiny_tds (0.6.2-x86-mingw32)

Comment: What's the x at the end of the statement doing? That looks wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I woke up this morning and realized it must have to do with the character set of the file on disk.  The following is a solution works [without changing the query]:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql0.join(" ").encode("UTF-8"))
```

I forced the character-set to utf-8 when submitting it, and now everything executes fine.

Proof:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Result:0x3bede68
 @column_types={},
 @columns=[""],
 @hash_rows=nil,
 @rows=[["pass"]]>

#<ActiveRecord::Result:0x3bf2c68
 @column_types={},
 @columns=[""],
 @hash_rows=nil,
 @rows=[["pass"]]>

"SELECT (CASE WHEN freq = 0 THEN 'pass' ELSE 'fail' END) FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) freq FROM Grant_Award WHERE Grant_Award.org_ticker IS NULL )x;"

#<ActiveRecord::Result:0x3bf5410
 @column_types={},
 @columns=[""],
 @hash_rows=nil,
 @rows=[["pass"]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the statement generated by the file import should be:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN freq = 0 THEN 'pass' ELSE 'fail' END) FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) freq FROM Grant_Award WHERE Grant_Award.org_ticker IS NULL );"
```

I think the x at the end of the statement is causing the error and wonder if this has slipped into your other lines by mistake.

Comment: TSql requires a label for the subquery.  Sql Server will throw an error without the label.  I use a lower case "x" to give it a visually low profile and to not distract from the rest of the code, given the label is functionally useless in this query.

Comment: Ah! I'd normally put an AS between the subquery and the x.

Comment: I'm learning little bits here and there, as I have not had to deal with code pages before.  The string in the code, sql2 or sql1, is encoded US-ASCII.  The string read from the file, sql0, is encoded IBM437.  I'm not sure if IBM437 is typical, but that is the way my laptop is configured.  When I force the code page to UTF-8, all is good with the world.

Comment: I tried adding "encoding: utf-8" to my database.yml, hoping activerecord/tinytds would pick that up and do the conversion internally, but no dice.  I have to explicitly force the code change.

Comment: One nit-picky comment to add.  Can the -1 be removed from my question?  I really think the problem and solution is noteworthy, and I don't want someone to ignore this post when they might receive some benefit from it.

Comment: I agree. The need to force encoding isn't obvious IMO.